# HERE Search parameter 'r' not functioning

Tags: flutter, here-api

I am calling the public transit v8 like this

```
    https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=51.492597,-0.156927;r=1000&return=transport&apiKey=my_key
```

However, no matter what i change the `r` value to it continues search the default distance, whether i put it higher or lower than `500`, it returns the same.

Documentation states - `{lat},{lng}[;r={radius}]` and all example show `lat,long;r=x`

I am sure I am using the correct formatting

Does anyone know why this may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try r=20 and r=50 you'll see a different number of stations returned.

There is an optional parameter maxPlaces that has some default value. If you change this it should return more stations for when r is set to larger numbers. For example:

```
https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=51.492597,-0.156927;r=500&return=transport&maxPlaces=50&apiKey=my_key
```

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter between query params is an ampersand (`&`) not a semicolon (`;`).

Maybe change `;r=1000` to `&r=1000`

Comment: The documentation states the how it must be called and it is {lat},{lng}[;r={radius}], with radius as an optional parametre

Comment: Noted. I don't have any other suggestion except maybe you want to report to the API owner.